# Function to foreach over an array

Tags: c, iteration, callback

I made a very simple generic function to foreach over an array in C using a callback function:

```
#include <stddef.h>
void foreach_array(void* array, size_t size, size_t bytes_per_element, void (*callback)(void*)) {
    char* iter;
    for(iter = array; iter < (char*)array + (int)size; iter += (int)bytes_per_element) {
        callback((void*)iter);
    }
}
```

It can be used like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print_double(void* doubleToPrint) {
    printf("%f\n", *((double*)doubleToPrint));
}

int main() {
    double myArray[] = {3.0, 6.0, 9.0};
    foreach_array(myArray, sizeof(myArray), sizeof(*myArray), print_double);
}
```

Comments:

- I had to use `char*` instead of `void*` for the iteration variable, Because the standard doesn't define pointer arithmetic on `void*`.
- I typecasted the `size` and `bytes_per_element` arguments to an `int` because I wasn't sure if it was defined behavior to use pointer arithmetic using a `size_t` value.

I thought this foreach function was interesting, So I wanted to put it here for a code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's unavoidably quite complex to use, you need to provide 3 arguments to describe the array (start, size, element_size) and a function accepting a single element as a `void*`-argument:
Writing the loop manually is far simpler.

To top it of, you cannot pass any context to your callback, meaning it can only work on global state. That's all kinds of unfortunate.

Now, let's look at your implementation:
You are far too cast-happy.

- The casts to `int` are wrong, `SIZE_MAX` can be bigger than `INT_MAX`. Anyway they are superfluous because yes you can use a `size_t` for pointer-arithmetic.
- The cast to `void*` is superfluous, it would be implicitly converted.

Incorporating that all gives you:

```
#include <stddef.h>
void foreach_array(
    void* array,
    size_t size,
    size_t bytes_per_element,
    void (*callback)(void* context, void* element),
    void* context
) {
    for(char* iter = array; iter < (char*)array + size; iter += bytes_per_element)
        callback(context, iter);
}
```

Comment: How would I use the context parameter?

Comment: It's a pointer for passing any additional info to the callback. Just point it at whatever is needed.